# Keeping databases open in Java agent IBM Domino / Lotus

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I have a Java agent. 
When I run the agent I also create a object which is opening databases.
This is the code of the databases class:

```
public class Databases {
    Database OrdersDB;
    Database CustomersDB;
    Database ItemsDB; 
    Database TablesDB; 
    Database ItemsDB;

    public Databases() throws NotesException{
    }

    public boolean openAllDatabases(Session session){

        try {

            OrdersDB = session.getDatabase(getServerName(session,"ORDER"),globalSettings.OrderDB, false);
            CustomersDB= session.getDatabase(getServerName(session,"CUSTOMER"),globalSettings.CustomerDB, false);
            TablesDB= session.getDatabase(getServerName(session,"TABLES"),globalSettings.TablesDB, false);
            ItemsDB = session.getDatabase(getServerName(session,"ITEMS"),globalSettings.ItemsDB, false);
            return true;
        } catch (NotesException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Database not opened!");
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Throughout the agent I use this Database obj. Also in my agent I create another class in which i pass this database obj as parameter and also use the databases there.
Finally when my agent is done I recycle all the databases and set the database Obj to null.

I wonder if this a good practice to do?
I already tried to open and close database whenever needed but because the code is to big I will get null pointer exceptions if I wrongly for example recycled the database in another class.
Thats why I keep open the databases at the start of the agent and recycle them at the end.
But I do not know if this causes memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about not recycling databases. When the agent is finished all databases will recycled automatically.

It is only important to recycle Domino object if you instantiate those by hundreds or thousands like running through all entries in a view.

Comment: Thanks.
I recycle most of my domino objects like Documents at the end of my agent. Or whenever an error arises. Is that also OK?

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. The only pitfall could be that you recycle a document in an inner loop although it is assign to another variable somewhere outside (it's rarely - we had it once).

Comment: Documents and Items are generally the important things to recycle, because those are the things that you tend to loop through, and sometimes it's hundreds of thousands of documents and many, many items per document. But as Knut said, if you're accessing the same actual document in multiple parts of your code, you don't want to recycle the Document objects until you're done with all instances of it. That's a perfect use-case for a container object like the one you've deisgned for your databases -- or for using the OpenNTF version of the Domino ojbects, which handles all recycling for you!

Comment: I really need to know how to use the openNTF database one day, can I use it with my existing agents @RichardSchwartz ?

Comment: You can review the documentation here. https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API/summary